# mysql howto access temporary table generated by subquery in another subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, subquery

I tried this:

```
    SELECT ProductId AS GmId, (
    SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM tmp WHERE ProductId=GmId AND (AssignDate BETWEEN '$Date1' AND '$Date2')
) AS sum0, (
    SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM tmp WHERE ProductId=GmId AND (AssignDate BETWEEN '$Date2' AND '$Date3')
) AS sum1 FROM (
    SELECT * FROM somerealtable
) tmp GROUP BY ProductId
```

But mysql displays error message `table <database name>.tmp doesn't exist!`

How to make this work?

EDIT: sqlfiddle sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b5ea/2)

EDIT2: more complicated sqlfiddle [sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d53653/1).

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Temporary tables, though not shown in your question (so where are they?), are per-session and are not accessible across sessions, in order words `A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the current connection`

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b5ea/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use **subquery**. Yo can do the same thing with **JOIN**

Try this:

```
SELECT a.ProductId AS GmId, 
       SUM(IF(b.AssignDate BETWEEN '$Date1' AND '$Date2', b.Amount, 0)) AS sum0, 
       SUM(IF(b.AssignDate BETWEEN '$Date2' AND '$Date3', b.Amount, 0)) AS sum1
FROM somerealtable a
LEFT JOIN tmp b ON a.ProductId=b.GmId 
GROUP BY ProductId
```

Comment: `SUM(IF(b.AssignDate BETWEEN '$Date1' AND '$Date2', b.Amount, 0))` - this is nice trick. Did not know `IF` can do that. Displays the result as expected. Thanks.